# Using Navigator inside setState

Tags: flutter, setstate

I have a list of Strings (called questions).
I create a Text widget based on the current string in the list.
I have an index int that increases every time a button is pressed.
I increase the current index by 1 in the setState method.
I need to navigate to a different page when the current index reaches the length of the String list.
Otherwise, I will get an RangeError naturally.

```
setState(() {
  this.currentIndex++;
  if(this.currentIndex == questions.length) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Loser()),
    );
  }
});
```

Now based on the code above, the error page appears and disappears quickly.
It is replaced by the Loser() page quickly.

Why is that?

And how can I navigate to the Loser() page without the error page showing?

Edit: As requested, the error message:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════

The following RangeError was thrown building LandingPage(dirty, state: _LandingPageState#a8efe):

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..10: 11

The relevant error-causing widget was
    LandingPage 
lib/main.dart:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:153:60)
#1      _LandingPageState.build 
package:testing_http_package/landing_page.dart:88
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4628
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4511
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4684
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Edit: The widget I think in the build method that is causing the error:

```
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            questions[currentIndex], // This line
            style: style,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Shouldn't the setState method go straight to the page before rerunning the build method?

Edit: I added the didChangeDependencies method as per @Nuts suggestion but it did not work. Now only the error page appears and it does not proceeds to the other page:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { 
      if(this.currentIndex == questions.length) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Loser()),
        );
      }
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: What is the error message, are you using Navigator inside build method?

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: I have attached the error message. I'm using the setState inside a method that is called when a button is pressed.

Comment: Could you post full error? Looks like it's not Navigator error

Comment: I am so sorry. I thought I copies the full error message earlier. I have updated it now. Now it's not a navigator error. It's just a stupid RangeError. I want to signal the end of the quiz and go to new page with results. That's why I entered the navigator right after the index was incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With setState - you are rebuilding the whole widget and while doing it - navigating. So you are trying to rebuild widgets with invalid params (in your case index)

```
    this.currentIndex++;
    if(this.currentIndex => questions.length) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Loser()),
      );
    }
   else setState(() {}); // if currentIndex is valid, just rebuild
```